# Inverting Op amp with 60 degree phase shift instead of 180

Tags: inverting-amplifier

I designed this 741 inverting op amp with a gain of 50. After wiring and testing I obtained a gain of 130 and a phase of 60 degrees. I don't understand why the phase is not 180. Also I switched the 741 with a MCP642 and did not see a noticeable change.
Assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

R1 = 6.8 k Ohm
R2 = 330 k Ohm

[image: Design for inverting Op-Amp]
[image: Oscilloscope output for inverting Op-amp]

Comment: Read up on the gain-bandwidth product of op-amps. https://ece.uncc.edu/sites/ece.uncc.edu/files/media/ecgr3156-experiment-5--gain-bandwidth-product-and-slew-rate.pdf may be relevant.

Comment: @Transistor How could low GBW (or low bandwidth) increase gain?

Comment: It wouldn't. I'm talking through my hat. 2 kHz x 130 < 1 MHz, the 741's max GBW product. I'll delete the comment in a while.

Comment: Did you use bypass capacitors? Could you measure actual resistance of those resistors?

Comment: Your scope appears to be showing a gain of 114.7 so I'd double check you have the correct resistors and not some stupid values.

Answer (score 2):

Thank you all for your help. I have figured out why the behavior is weird and the answer is due to my incompetence. Forgot to add a second oscilloscope channel for the input on the board. I am not sure how the channel was displaying a voltage already. Now what it is outputting makes sense. Thanks again.
[image: Proper Oscilloscope output with correct input data.]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an intuitive explanation. The math is straightforward, maybe someone else will do that:

Consider the open-loop response of the 741, which has the typical single-pole compensation response, with the pole at ~10Hz (4Hz here)  [from here](https://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/18-physical-current-source-output-impedance-1-kn-drives-current-voltage-converter-shown-fi-q42216678). Compensation is designed to make the op-amp gain drop below 1 when the frequency is high enough that the output phase shift approaches 180° so that it's stable with all negative feedback resistive feedback networks.

[image]

You have a frequency of about 2kHz and a gain of about 110, so you can see the op-amp doesn't have enough excess gain to make the phase shift closer to the ideal 180°. If you reduce the frequency below 2kHz or decrease the gain by changing the resistor ratio you'll see a change in the phase shift to make it closer to 180°.

Also note the visible crossover distortion in your output.

Answer (score 0):

You could say that the  output is leading the input by 61 degrees but in reality the output is lagging the input by 299 degrees.

The output lags the input by 180 degrees at low frequency. This lag increases beyond 180 degrees as frequency increases

With such a high gain the lag will increase fairly rapidly as frequency increases reaching 45 degrees (actually 225) at the -3dB frequency.